Record Internal System Audio On Mac
I am trying to record Internal System Audio on Mac.I found that it is possible to record it without virtual audio driver. After bit research I am going with Blackhole. Problem with blackhole is it doesn't playback audio on speakers. I want to play real time audio back to speakers too.
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import threading

# Set sample rate and device indices
sample_rate = 48000  # Sample rate
input_device = 2  # Unbounded 2ch (adjust as needed)
output_device = 1  # MacBook Air Speakers (adjust as needed)

# Initialize buffer and lock
buffer_lock = threading.Lock()
playback_buffer = np.zeros((0, 2), dtype='float32')  # Start with an empty buffer

def audio_callback(indata, frames, time, status):
    global playback_buffer
    if status:
        print("Callback status:", status)

    # Print shape of the input data for debugging
    print(f"Input data shape: {indata.shape}, frames: {frames}")

    # Append incoming audio data to the buffer
    with buffer_lock:
        playback_buffer = np.concatenate((playback_buffer, indata), axis=0)

def playback():
    global playback_buffer
    while True:
        with buffer_lock:
            if playback_buffer.shape[0] > 0:
                # Play the audio chunk and clear the buffer
                audio_chunk = playback_buffer.copy()  # Copy buffer
                playback_buffer = np.zeros((0, 2), dtype='float32')  # Reset buffer
                print("Playing back audio...")
                try:
                    sd.play(audio_chunk, samplerate=sample_rate, device=output_device)
                    sd.wait()  # Wait until the playback finishes
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Playback error: {e}")
        sd.sleep(10)  # Small sleep to prevent busy waiting

if __name__ == "__main__":
    playback_thread = threading.Thread(target=playback, daemon=True)
    playback_thread.start()

    # Start recording from the input device
    with sd.InputStream(samplerate=sample_rate, channels=2, dtype='float32', device=input_device,
                        callback=audio_callback, blocksize=2048):  # Reduced blocksize for lower latency
        print("Recording and playing back in real-time. Press Ctrl+C to stop.")

        try:
            while True:
                sd.sleep(1000)  # Keep the stream alive
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Stopping...")

I tried to use this python script but failed to play real time audio. Also this is blackhole DoIOOperation function I think it deals with audio. I am not sure how to edit that for my use case. Any help would be appreciated.
I cant use Multi Audio Setup because it would be an extra step for my users unless I can automate that.

You can capture system audio withScreenCaptureKit on macOS 13.0 and up or CATap on macOS 14.0 and up.
